# My master branch files moved to another branch, i want to get back the changes

Tags: git, github

I'm afraid. I was following a guide to deploy the project on Github pages.
I did all that guide said. I created another branch then made changes to that branch to test that it will work or not. But that's not working for me now. But the problem is how my master branch files moved to the new branch.
My files are no longer shows up in the master branch(Github). It shows in git.
How I did this or how it happens? also how to go back or revert files back to master branch from deploy branch

[image: git ls for both branch]

shows the same files for both but GitHub shows different

[image: Deploy branch github]
[image: Master branch github]

[image: git log]
Check this "git log --online" commits.
shows deploy has 2 commits and master contain prev all commits.
but, Why Github shows differently?

For your information, what I did as I remember. I created another branch/B for test the deployment. I installed dependencies for that project, did minor changes in a file and committed to that branch if I am right.
Also, I made branch deploy default in Github for deployment as guide suggested.
Maybe that one created the problem.

Comment: Be careful with the advice you receive.  Resetting a branch has the ability to lose history.  Be sure to write down the commit you are at just in case you don't get the result you want (`git rev-parse HEAD`), that way you can reset the branch back to that commit in case it wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want.  What should master show?  What should branch/B show?  What should deploy show?  Even better, what commit should they be at?  What are the local versions of these branches showing?  You gave some information on two of them, but it sounds like there are 3 involved.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister There are two total branches. First one master and 2nd one deploy. after my process. I am seeing files of both branches in git. but it shows differently in GitHub. But my problem is that master branch doesn't show previous files that were from starting. but deploy shows all files as you can see in the ss.

Comment: I still don't understand what your desired outcome is. :-(  You mentioned branch/B (a third branch)--where did it go?  If all you want is to make GitHub the same as your local master, then you just need to push the master branch up into the remote repo.  That's a pretty fundamental step to be missing though, so if you're new to Git, you probably want to work through a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new branch with the history of remote's master branch:

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout -b master2 origin/master

# now if 'master2' branch is ok, then replace 'master' with 'master2'
$ git branch -D master  # delete the local master branch

# create & checkout to a new local 'master' branch = master2 = origin/master
$ git checkout -b master
```

Now, `master2` branch should have the same history with `origin/master`

**OR**, you can `reset` your local master with the history remote/master

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch master.bac  # backup just for safety
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

**EDIT:**

---

I got the issue observing your [repo](https://github.com/Ckbhatia/portfolio/commits/master) that your local `master` branch is not updated. Just update the local master:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master
```

N.B. the previous solutions should also work.

Comment: I have a problem with master branch. As you can see master branch doesn't show history. I want to see my files in master branch, not in 2nd or another branch.

Comment: If you follow the `reset` options then you should see the files back in your local `master` branch. Can you check?

Comment: reset in Github or git reset?

Comment: `git reset` locally (in your terminal)

Comment: Be sure to write down the commit you are at just in case you don't get the result you want (`git rev-parse HEAD`).  That way you can reset back to that commit in case it wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: Please make sure that I will not lose my files and previous commits by following your suggestions.

Comment: @SajibKhan I updated the main thread. added the log to understand the situation better. check it

Comment: ok, what is the output of `git fetch; git log origin/master` &  `git log origin/develop`?

Comment: The issue is your local master is not updated. Update master: `git checkout master; git pull origin master`